# Spring validation messages are not displaying in JSP using internal resource view resolver

Tags: spring-mvc

MVC controller, facing issue in validation message in `JSP`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerSuccess(@Valid @ModelAttribute Registerbean register, Model model, Errors error) {
    if (error.hasErrors()) {
        return "Registration";
    } else {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more details? what is actually happening? is there any error message/log/weird behaviour?

Comment: validation messages are not displaying in JSP getting below exception   org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'registerbean' on field 'firstname': rejected value []; codes [Length.registerbean.firstname,Length.firstname,Length.java.lang.String,Length]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [registerbean.firstname,firstname]; arguments []; default message [firstname],2147483647,5]; default message [The field must be at least 5 characters]

Comment: I've added the exception in your question.. anywho this line `The field must be at least 5 characters` seems like something that may help you. how are you defining the fields?